# How to render multiple scenes in succession from the timeline?

Tags: rendering, compositing-nodes, scene

I've seen over the internet different ways of linking multiple scenes between each other and using multiple cameras from a single scene, but is there any way to render completely different scenes with their own cameras one after another like in After Effects?

I mean in AE there is a way to put *compositions* one after another to create a single video file.

Could it be done similarly in Blender, so I won't get several different video files which require video editing to merge them?

Comment: What do mean completely different scenes? In blender you can create several scenes and than use Video Sequence Editor (often called as VSE) to combine those Scenes as a strips and mix them on timeline ... Also you can choose what scene camera will be used.

Comment: You can also use the Compositor to blend in different view layers from different scenes. Please add a little more information about the expected behaviour

Comment: @vklidu Lets say we have in scene 1 with room A and scene 2 with room B. When I try to render video it always renders only active scene cameras. So I have to render 2 times and then manually combine these scenes. Is there a way to combine both scenes? Thank you for you advice. I will check it out

Answer (score 11, accepted):

For rendering more Scenes created in one blend file use Video Sequencer (called VSE).

Scene_Cube
[image]

Scene_Sphere
[image]

Create a third **New** scene, switch to *Video Editing* layout and  with mouse hovering above **Video Sequencer** editor *Add* <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> Scene strips and organised on *Timeline* as needed.

[image]

From *Video Sequencer* properties panel <kbd>N</kbd> (with *Scene* strip selected in timeline) under *Strip > Scene > Camera* you can choose what camera object should be used (if you have more than one in that scene).

Or you can also use one camera in *Scene_Cube* linked to *Scene_Sphere*.

Comment: thank you! now I understand

Comment: Huh, that's a pretty neat idea :).

Comment: @JachymMichal commonly used ... and available from blender's beginning ... in this area was blender for almost two decades hidden rockstar next to an 3D packages and Compositing packs. They handled this by very complicated and separated import/export system or it was totally impossible for them... I remember one complex project I did entirely in this system and it was pleasure to work with even in that time :)