# Switch main viewlayers during render

Tags: rendering, scene, viewlayers

I have a scene with a lot of different cameras and camera angles and I used the viewlayers to quickly show or hide objects depending of what these cameras should render. It was much quicker than keyframing the "show in the viewport/render" option for each of the items that should be hidden or not (especially when said items were to be shown again later in the video).

Now I have my scene with cameras tied to markers in my timeline, and each camera's corresponding viewlayer set up, how should I set up my render to render every layer according to it's camera use without having to render each viewlayer manually (as in; selecting a viewlayer and the frames' array, waiting for it to render and do the same for the next sequence, making it impossible to start the render and go to sleep for example) ?

The only changes between viewlayers are what elements are currently masked or not, I am not using them for composition-related stuff. I'm pretty sure viewlayers were not really designed to do this but I honestly don't know any better. Thanks

Edit: I made as many scenes as I had viewlayers with my elements in each of them set up similarly (you can read the comments to see how I'm using those with the sequencer (also do not do as i did with my first empty "master" scene nested in a second empy scene as it doubles the render time for some reason) and I noticed (after way too long scratching my head) that the "Disable in Render" was a global feature meaning I couldn't disable one Element in one scene and have it visible in the next scene. Why does that ferature works like that while the "Disable in viewport" works on a local basis is lost on me. Please help if you know how to work around this!

Edit II; As I'm quite in a hurry, I settled on keyframing the "Show on render" property for each of the objects. Hopefully someone will find a proper solution to this without having to use collections.

Comment: maybe this https://fishsnackart.gumroad.com/l/nsgkn helps you?

Comment: I stumbled upon it before posting and it seems aimed at people doing a lot of compositions and lots of different passes in blender. Maybe not but either way it's a bit too complex for me sadly. I'll try to use scenes which looks like they were designed for that instead. thanks !

Comment: I've found this on [Right Click Select](https://blender.community/c/rightclickselect/2vfbbc/?sorting=hot), people there say we can use [background scenes](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/scene_layout/scene/properties.html#scene)

Comment: It would be a lot of work to refactor the file to work with the backgound scene (i guess, clean up a scene from all the moving objects, use it as a bg scene and the create full copy of other scenes containing only the objects specific to that scene), I'll investigate. Thanks again, let's take it to the chat when you'll be able to.

Answer (score 0):

This has already been asked and answered [here](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/222118/how-to-render-multiple-scenes-in-succession-from-the-timeline) and [here](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/6277/different-camera-settings-for-different-render-layers), you need to use scenes instead of viewlayers. with viewlayers you can hide and unhide objects, but to change cameras and render settings you need to use a separate scene.

After setting up the scenes you create a new, empty scene and add the scenes you want to render to the sequencer (Add > Scene)

Comment: Thanks, I have created linked scenes for each of my sequences, replacing the corresponding layers. I now have troubles to render them through the sequencer on my blank scene, as if it wasn't switching between scenes but would instead stay on the same scene without accounting for the editing. All my scenes are cut and assembled following each each other on the same channel in the sequencer. The editor's preview seems to work as intended most of the time. I must be missing something.

Comment: I'm going to render a second blank scene with the first one inserted in it and its input set at 'sequencer' tonight and see if I can investigate further tomorrow.

Comment: I thought I was losing my mind when I finally understood that while the "" button to hide or show an element in the viewport would be scene-specific, the "" button to do the same is not, and disabling it in one scene disables it in every scene, totally blewing the very reason i was doing all that... I can't understand why is something apparently so simple is so hard to do on my side. Is it because my scenes are linked? Please help!

Comment: The description of the "" button says that it disables the object in renders, if you change this on an object it will do the same on the linked copy.
You can use the full copy function, but that takes up WAY more space.
I'll try to find a method that doesn't require copying every object, something like visibility override.

Comment: Yeah, that's why I went with the linked copy, but I thought it wouldn't link this property since the viewport one is locally-based. As my file is too messy for disabling collections (e.g. some objects should be shown and some other hidden in the same collection) I fear the only solution left would be to keyframe each "disputed" object's "show in>render" property. That's what I used to do but it's really not an ideal way to deal with that, hence why I used viewlayers then scenes. Thanks for your help.

Comment: I will continue to look for a better way to do this, and we should also move this conversation to the chat as soon as I have enough reputation. @Gam